# Getting array of array of strings with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm new to Swift, sorry if this is a dumb question...
there seem to be many questions about this but I can't find my answer
I need to get an array of array

here is my request

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            var resp = JSON(response.value as! NSDictionary)
            id = resp["Data"].arrayValue.map({$0["Id"].stringValue})
            name = resp["Data"].arrayValue.map({$0["Name"].stringValue})
            break

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
```

and here's the JSON response:

```
{
Data =(
    { 
        Id = "u1";
        Name = "user 1";
        Users =({
                FullName = "aaa";
                UserName = "aaa";
            }
        );
    },
    {
        Id = "u2";
        Name = "user 2";
        Users =({
                FullName = "bbb";
                UserName = "bbb";
            },
            {
                FullName = "ccc";
                UserName = "ccc";
            }
        );
    })}
```

I have no problem to get arrays of id and name but I don't know how to get array of users, any help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let users = resp["Data"].arrayValue.map({$0["Users"]})
```

Your should be able to get an array of users.